# Does C preprocessed file contain source file line number information?

Tags: c

Here is the problem:
I have a C source file `main.c` and the corresponding preprocessed file `main.i`. Given a line in `main.i`, how can I get the corresponding line number in `main.c`?

Comment: *Does C preprocessed file contain source file line number information?*  Generally yes.  Did you take a look?  Look for `#line` or maybe bare `#` directives.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard does not specify this. [GCC and Clang emit lines starting with `#` followed by a space, a line number, a file name, and other information.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html). You can determine the line number in `main.c`:

- Read the preprocessed file, `main.i`. After any line with `#` followed by a space, a number, and a file name that is not “main.c”, read and ignore further lines until there is a `#` followed by a space, a number, and “main.c”. Remember that number as the current line number.
- Subsequent lines until another `#` line in this form are lines from `main.c` (after preprocessing) with consecutive line numbers continuing from the line number remembered above.

Answer (score 2):

When used as a separate phase to produce a text file, the C preprocessor usually inserts `#line` directives, sometimes appearing as bare `#` directives providing the original line number, file name and other contextual information. `#line` directives have this form:

`#` `line` *pp-tokens* *new-line*

which after macro substitution should become:

`#` `line` *digit-sequence* *new-line*

or

`#` `line` *digit-sequence* `"` *s-char-sequence<sub>opt</sub>* `"` *new-line*

Where *digit-sequence* is the line number of the next list in the source stream and the *s-char-sequence<sub>opt</sub>* is the name of the file to use for diagnostics and as a replacement for the `__FILE__` macro. Subsequent newlines increment the line number thus defined.

`#line` directives are produced by external programs that generate C code files to make compiler diagnostics point to the original source file.

C Compilers such as *gcc* and *clang* produce similar information in their preprocessing output in the form:

`#` *number* *filename* *other-information* *new-line*

This syntax is not defined by the C Standard but very common in preprocessing output produced by C compilers. The C standard does not define this output, used mostly for debugging purposes.

Comment: `#line` directives are used by other software to tell the compiler/preprocessor that the source text comes from (or should be treated as if it comes from) specific lines in some other file. What GCC and Clang emit to indicate line numbers is not `#line` directives but directives that are `#` followed by a space, a number, and other information.